# How do I set up a small mailing list / newsletter with Gmail?

Tags: gmail, google-workspace, mailing-list

Can I setup kind of a mailing list / newsletter from my Gmail / GApps account?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I use [Google Groups](http://groups.google.com/) with my friends. If you have Google Account (e.g. you already use Gmail), you can use it. It's basicaly a simple mailing list with on-line searchable archive.

Answer (score 4):

[In the 'Contacts' section you can define groups of contacts](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=30970).

[Then in the 'To' box, the group name will come up as a suggestion when you start to type it just like for individuals](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=30973).

Comment: You can type group names in any of the boxes, not only 'To'. This means that you can keep the addresses of people private (by putting the group into the 'Bcc' field).

Comment: the problem with this approach is that the other users can't mail back to all others (mailinglist). for a newsletter this approach is ok.

Answer (score 1):

i'm following up from the last user's comment on a newsletter creator for Gmail called http://Flashissue.com (full disclosure - i'm the founder).

we've had a HTML authoring tool for Gmail for a while - it lets you create a full styled newsletter and helps with finding and adding content to the newsletter rapidly. you then send out the newsletters through your gmail contacts.

we've had a lot of requests for "mailing list" support and analytics for newsletters sent through gmail. we'll be adding both shortly.

the web app is free to use. let me know if you need anymore help.

BTW you're best off installing it through the chrome store using this link as suggested above:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/newsletter-creator-by-fla/cihaednhfbocfdiflmpccekcmjepcnmb?hl=en

Comment: "Last user"? I assume you mean based on the date of the post. Note that answers can be sorted in several different ways, so terms like "last", "previous", "above", really have no context here.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a contact group, but then no one can easily sign up for your list or manage their on subscription.  Also if your list gets too large, spam filters might start blocking your emails.  Some very popular solutions for a distribution list are [Binhost](http://www.binhost.com/) and [Mailman](http://www.gnu.org/software/mailman/index.html)

Comment: s/solutiosn/solutions/

Comment: Thanks, totally fat fingered that one, don't know why I didn't notice the browser spelling correction.

Answer (score 0):

I don't mean to spam* but there is a startup called [FlashIssue](http://www.flashissue.com/) is working on a [product](http://www.flashissue.com/blog/gmail-adds-a-newsletter-creator-mailing-lists-analytics/) that does this

They already have [chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/newsletter-creator-by-fla/cihaednhfbocfdiflmpccekcmjepcnmb?hl=en-US&utm_source=chrome-ntp-launcher) that lets you export the existing newsletter to a new gmail email message (the new product seems to offer more gmail integration such as [mailing lists and analytics](http://www.flashissue.com/blog/gmail-adds-a-newsletter-creator-mailing-lists-analytics/))

(*I'm not affiliated, just know one of the developers who work there, they seem likea great company)