# Gmail as a mailinglist

Tags: gmail, mailing-list

Hello
Is there a way to use an gmail accout as a mailinglist.

Right now we are having some problems at my job with our email. We are moving over to another system but in the mean time we need to have a mailinglist that is one email we can send to to communicate with all the employees.

Example:
Send email to everyone@gmail.com and the mail will go to everyone signed up.

Who can you do this well with google?
Dose everyone have to confirm with the confirmation code?
What is an easyer way to do this that is spam free?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is already a thred for this: [How do I set up a small mailing list / newsletter with Gmail?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/462/how-do-i-set-up-a-small-mailing-list-newsletter-with-gmail)

Tryed to search for it. Will see if it solves my problems

Comment: Glad you found something. If it has the exact same needs as this question please delete this question